# How to format a list of strings into

Tags: java, list, string-formatting

I have a list of strings that I want to format each of them in the same way.  e.g. myListOfStrings = str1, str2, str3, and my format is (%s)
I want to have something like this:

```
String.format(" (%s) ", myListOfStrings)
```

Will output

```
(str1)  (str2)  (str3)
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this? or do I have to use a string builder and do a foreach loop on all the strings?

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: Well, StringBuilder seems obvious , can you provide an example of the code (using SB) so we better understand what you mean , please.

Comment: You can use StringBuilder(if you don't want thread safe) or use string buffer

Comment: can't you have a wrapper class for your list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with Java 8:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

    final String joined = strings.stream()
            .collect(joining(") (", "(", ")"));

    System.out.println(joined);
}
```

Or:

```
final String joined = strings.stream()
        .map(item -> "(" + item + ")")
        .collect(joining(" "));
```

Which one you prefer is a matter of personal preference.

The first joins the items on `) (` which gives:

a) (b) (c

Then you use the prefix and suffix arguments to `joining` to with prefix  with `(` and suffix with `)`, to produce the right outcome.

The second alternative transforms each item to `( + item + )` and then joins them on " ".

The first might also be somewhat faster, as it only requires the creation of **one** `StringBuilder` instance - for both the join and the pre/suffix. The second alternative requires the creation of **n + 1** `StringBuilder` instances, one for each element and one for the join on " ".

Answer (score 5):

if you want a one-line solution, you could use one of the the [StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) methods in Apache Commons Lang.

```
String result = "(" + StringUtils.join(myListOfStrings, ") (") + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("str1");
list.add("str2");
list.add("str3");
        
for(String s : list) {
  System.out.print(String.format(" (%s) ", s));
}
```

Comment: This is running three separate print statements, looks like OP needs one print statement

Answer (score 0):

```
String strOut = "";
for(int i=0; i< myListOfStrings.size(); i++){
    strOut = strOut +"("+myListOfStrings.get(i)+")";
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java8 new [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) method for iterating over collections:

```
public static String format(List<String> list) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    list.forEach(x -> sb.append(String.format(" (%s) ", x)));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Try it here: https://ideone.com/52EKRH

Comment: Eugh - I don't like this at all. It mixes formatting with output is a very ugly way. It also should probably us `printf` rather than both `format` and `print`. Or use a `map` then a `print`. Either way, I think this isn't a good approach.

Comment: @BoristheSpider (agree on the printf, yet-) it is much more readable than both the stream/map/collect and than the joining forms

Comment: @BoristheSpider did you ever use a logger at all?

Comment: Logging if for debugging purposes **not** business logic.

Comment: Your new code is much better, but I think that if you have a `StringBuilder` then _use one_ - skip the `format` entirely and its overhead...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I honestly don't see how decorating data like this could fit business logic; anyway, it is true that String.format introduces some overhead for this simple example (parsing the format pattern): but _in general_, it is used for his added features (locale) and because the OP asks to use it, hopefully for some good reason, I sticked to it. Again, if there is no specific requirement asking for best performance (in this case it was asking for elegance), I would not sacrifice readability for some micro-optimizing away some constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Boris The Spider's answer is what I would go with, but in case you are not using java 8, but maybe you are using Guava you can do something like this, albeit it is a bit verbose:

```
Joiner.on("").join(Collections2.transform(myListOfStrings, new Function<String, String>() {

        @Override
        public String apply(String input) {
            return String.format(" (%s) ", input);
        }
    }));
```

Comment: This is similar to my second alternative that is less efficient. Also, it doesn't look like the OP wants the output to be pre/sufffixed with spaces -  you should join on a space as I did in my code.